# What are the current dutch tax brackets?

Tags: taxes, netherlands

I am trying to search for the brackets of taxation in the Netherlands.

I am sure there is a link somewhere but I am not good in Dutch. So, it would be great if someone share it with me.

Comment: You can find this on [Hoeveel inkomstenbelasting moet ik betalen?](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/nl/werk-en-inkomen/content/hoeveel-inkomstenbelasting-betalen). Note that the second and third bracket always had the same tax rate as far as I can remember but the tax office makes a distinction because in the third bracket all the money flows to the state budget whereas in the second bracket a big chunk goes to the basic pension system (AOW). This also means that retirees pay different rates.

Comment: You can add it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dutch tax brackets for 2017](https://www.expatax.nl/tax-rates-2017):

```
+-----------------------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+
| Taxable income        | Tax per | National  | Total  | Total per | Cumulative |
|                       | bracket | Insurance | rate   | bracket   |            |
|                       |         | Premium   |        |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+
| Of at     | But less  |         |           |        |           |            |       
| least     | than      |         |           |        |           |            |       
+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+
| €      0  | € 19,982  |  8.90%  |  27.65%   | 36.55% | €  7,303  |  €  7,303  |
| € 19,982  | € 33,791  | 13.15%  |  27.65%   | 40.80% | €  5,634  |  € 12,937  |
| € 33,791  | € 67,072  | 40.80%  |           | 40.80% | € 13,578  |  € 26,515  |
| € 67,072  |           | 52.00%  |           | 52.00% |           |            |
+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+--------+-----------+------------+
```